# Newtonian Mechanics - Pulley block system, finding acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

[image: Pulley Block diagram]
The question is to find acceleration of the block m<sub>1</sub> in the above system (please look at diagram). So I took tension along String 2 to be T and thus Tension along String 1 would be 2T.

Acceleration of m<sub>1</sub> I took to be 'a' (rightwards), so, as tension on the masses m<sub>2</sub> and m<sub>3</sub> is half that of m<sub>1</sub>, I took the acceleration of m<sub>2</sub> and m<sub>3</sub> to be '2a'.

Then I set up laws of motion equations

m<sub>3</sub>g - T = 2m<sub>3</sub>a for the mass m<sub>3</sub>

and, m<sub>2</sub>g - T = 2m<sub>2</sub>a for the mass m<sub>2</sub>

Then dividing each of them throughout by m<sub>3</sub> and m<sub>2</sub> and taking a on the LHS and adding, I got $a = T(1/m2-1/m3)/4$

But I cant eliminate T. Can someone help me on where I went wrong/ suggest amends in the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let a be the acceleration of m1 to the right.  This is also the downward acceleration of the pulley supporting m2 and m3.  Let $\delta$ be the downward acceleration of m3 *relative* to this pulley.  Then the absolute downward acceleration of m3 is $a+\delta$ and the absolute downward acceleration of m2 is $a-\delta$.  So the force balances read:  $$m_1a=2T$$
$$m_2(a-\delta)=m_2g-T$$ $$m_3(a+\delta)=m_3g-T$$

The key to doing many pulley problems is to first focus on the kinematics of the motion (as in this problem).